# Windows 10 reset couldn't delete my personal files - so where are they?

Tags: windows-10

I just used Windows 10's Reset option to clear out my PC and start over. I chose to delete everything, including my personal files etc.

At the end of the process, it told me it couldn't delete my personal files.

Well, I don't see any of the Users, and I don't see any of my old files. So my question is: what are those personal files Windows supposedly couldn't delete? Why did that happen?

Comment: Perhaps this is exactly why Windows cannot delete the personal files: none can be found.

Comment: That seems about impossible. Even an empty user account will have a Desktop, Documents, etc. folders and a user Registry hive.

Comment: Try to Reset from the [boot menu](https://www.howtogeek.com/126016/three-ways-to-access-the-windows-8-boot-options-menu/).

Answer (score 1):

I found some of my files here C:\$SysReset\OldOS

Comment: Read over https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.